# Jquery Slider error

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, slideshow

So I have my script running, (you can use sample links/images to test)
but I have an issue. After counting my images for length, it seems that
my "interim period" before the slider starts back / repeats itself is 
about triple the length of the images. We can test it by using sample
urls.

```
<a class='wrapper' href='http://www.universallifechurchministers.org/images/big_image/ConanObrien.jpg' title="Conan O'Brien: TV host, comedian, writer, producer and performer."><img class='logo' alt="TV host, comedian, writer, producer and performer." id='conanobrien' src='http://www.universallifechurchministers.org/images/conan-obrien-sm.jpg' /><div class='long'>[.....]</div></a>
<a class='wrapper' href='http://www.universallifechurchministers.org/images/big_image/RobDyrdek.jpg' title="Rob Dyrdek: Skateboarding Entrepreneur, Fantasy Factory on MTV."><img class='logo' alt="Skateboarding Entrepreneur, Fantasy Factory on MTV." id='robdyrdek' src='http://www.universallifechurchministers.org/images/rob-drydek-sm.jpg' /><div class='long'>[.....]</div></a>
<a class='wrapper' href='http://www.universallifechurchministers.org/images/big_image/Glann-Beck.jpg' title="Glenn Beck: Talk Radio Host"><img class='logo' alt="Talk Radio Host" id='glennbeck' src='http://www.universallifechurchministers.org/images/image1.jpg' /><div class='long'>[.....]</div></a>
<a class='wrapper' href='http://www.universallifechurchministers.org/images/big_image/Mel-Blanc.jpg' title="Mel Blanc: Voice Actor"><img class='logo' alt="Voice Actor" id='melblanc' src='http://www.universallifechurchministers.org/images/image2.jpg' /><div class='long'>[.....]</div></a>
```

left: -632.914px seems to what my slider stops at before it starts sliding again.
I would like it to start again immediately afterward at the end of the last image,
but cannot figure out what is stopping it from doing that?

[[You can see it working here](http://www.themonastery.org/jd/slider.php#)] and here's the full code source

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>

        /* js-disabled class - set image sizes so they all fit in the viewer */
        .js-disabled img { width:100px; height:100px; display:block; float:left; margin:30px 0 0; }
        .wrapper {padding: 0 5px;}
        .long { display:none; }

        #outerContainer { width:542px; height:202px; margin:auto; position:relative; margin:220px auto; }
        #imageScroller { width:675px; height:202px; position:relative; background: url(filmstrip_right.png) no-repeat; }
            #viewer {
                background-color: #000000;
                height: 72px;
                margin: auto;
                overflow: hidden;
                position: relative;
                right: 10px;
                top: 51px;
                width: 540px;
            }
        #imageScroller a:active, #imageScroller a:visited { color:#000000; }
        #imageScroller a img { border:0; }
            #controls {
                background: url("images/controlsBG.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
                height: 47px;
                left: 11px;
                position: absolute;
                top: -7px;
                width: 534px;
                z-index: 10;
            }

            #cover {
                background: url("images/cover.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
                height: 71px;
                left: 57px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 51px;
                width: 38px;
                z-index: 999;
            }
        #controls a { width:37px; height:35px; position:absolute; top:3px; }
        #controls a:active, #controls a:visited { color:#0d0d0d; }
        #title { color:#000; font-family:arial; font-size:13px; font-weight:bold; width:100%; text-align:center; margin-top:13px; }

    </style>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>[....]</title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div id="outerContainer">
            <div id="imageScroller">
                <div id="cover"></div>
                <div id="viewer" class="js-disabled">

                    <?php   include('famous/class/scraper.php');
                            $scrape = new Scraper('http://www.universallifechurchministers.org');
                            $scrape = (array)$scrape;

                        foreach($scrape as $multi) {
                         if(is_array($multi)) {

                            $holder = ''; 
                            foreach($multi as $single) {

                                foreach($single as $k=>$v)  { 
                                    switch($k) {
                                        case 'fimg': $fimg = $v; break;
                                        case 'simg': $simg = $v; break;
                                        case 'name': $name = $v; break;
                                        case 'note': $note = $v; break;
                                        case 'long': $long = $v; break; 
                                    }
                                }

                                    $id = strtolower( //clean
                                           str_replace("'",'',
                                           str_replace(' ','',$name)
                                          ));

                                /* sample output:   <a class='wrapper' href='[uri]/*-lrg.jpg' 
                                 *                     title='[note]'>
                                 *
                                 *                  <img class='logo' alt='[note]' id='[cleanName]' 
                                 *                       src='[uri]/*-sm.jpg' /></a>
                                 *
                                 *                  [....repeat....]
                                 */

                                $holder .= "<a class='wrapper' href='" . $fimg . "' title=\""
                                            . $name . ': ' . $note. "\"><img class='logo' alt=\"" . $note . "\" id='" 
                                            . $id . "' src='" 
                                            . $simg . "' /><div class='long'>"
                                            . $long . "</div></a>";
                            }
                         }
                        }

                        #echo $holder;

                    ?>

                    <!--// test-data //-->
                    <a class='wrapper' href='http://www.universallifechurchministers.org/images/big_image/ConanObrien.jpg' title="Conan O'Brien: TV host, comedian, writer, producer and performer."><img class='logo' alt="TV host, comedian, writer, producer and performer." id='conanobrien' src='http://www.universallifechurchministers.org/images/conan-obrien-sm.jpg' /><div class='long'>[.....]</div></a>
                    <a class='wrapper' href='http://www.universallifechurchministers.org/images/big_image/RobDyrdek.jpg' title="Rob Dyrdek: Skateboarding Entrepreneur, Fantasy Factory on MTV."><img class='logo' alt="Skateboarding Entrepreneur, Fantasy Factory on MTV." id='robdyrdek' src='http://www.universallifechurchministers.org/images/rob-drydek-sm.jpg' /><div class='long'>[.....]</div></a>
                    <a class='wrapper' href='http://www.universallifechurchministers.org/images/big_image/Glann-Beck.jpg' title="Glenn Beck: Talk Radio Host"><img class='logo' alt="Talk Radio Host" id='glennbeck' src='http://www.universallifechurchministers.org/images/image1.jpg' /><div class='long'>[.....]</div></a>
                    <a class='wrapper' href='http://www.universallifechurchministers.org/images/big_image/Mel-Blanc.jpg' title="Mel Blanc: Voice Actor"><img class='logo' alt="Voice Actor" id='melblanc' src='http://www.universallifechurchministers.org/images/image2.jpg' /><div class='long'>[.....]</div></a>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {

              //remove js-disabled class
                $("#viewer").removeClass("js-disabled");

              //create new container for images
                $("<div>").attr("id", "container").css({ position:"absolute"}).width($(".wrapper").length * 170).height(170).appendTo("div#viewer");

                //add images to container
                $(".wrapper").each(function() {
                    $(this).appendTo("div#container");
                });

                //work out duration of anim based on number of images (1 second for each image)
                var duration = $(".wrapper").length * 2000;

                //store speed for later (distance / time)
                var speed = (parseInt($("div#container").width()) + parseInt($("div#viewer").width())) / duration;

                //set direction
                var direction = "rtl";

                //set initial position and class based on direction
                (direction == "rtl") ? $("div#container").css("left", $("div#viewer").width()).addClass("rtl") : $("div#container").css("left", 0 - $("div#container").width()).addClass("ltr") ;

                //animator function
                var animator = function(el, time, dir) {

                    //which direction to scroll
                    if(dir == "rtl") {

                      //add direction class
                        el.removeClass("ltr").addClass("rtl");

                        //animate the el
                        el.animate({ left:"-" + el.width() + "px" }, time, "linear", function() {

                            //reset container position
                            $(this).css({ left:$("div#imageScroller").width(), right:"" });

                            //restart animation
                            animator($(this), duration, "rtl");

                            //hide controls if visible
                            ($("div#controls").length > 0) ? $("div#controls").slideUp("slow").remove() : null ;            

                        });
                    } else {

                      //add direction class
                        el.removeClass("rtl").addClass("ltr");

                        //animate the el
                        el.animate({ left:$("div#viewer").width() + "px" }, time, "linear", function() {

                            //reset container position
                            $(this).css({ left:0 - $("div#container").width() });

                            //restart animation
                            animator($(this), duration, "ltr");

                            //hide controls if visible
                            ($("div#controls").length > 0) ? $("div#controls").slideUp("slow").remove() : null ;            
                        });
                    }
                }

                //start anim
                animator($("div#container"), duration, direction);

                //pause on mouseover
                $("a.wrapper").live("mouseover", function() {

                    //stop anim
                    $("div#container").stop(true);

                    //show controls
                    ($("div#controls").length == 0) ? $("<div>").attr("id", "controls").appendTo("div#outerContainer").css({ opacity:0.7 }).slideDown("slow") : null ;
                    ($("a#rtl").length == 0) ? $("<a>").attr({ id:"rtl", href:"#", title:"rtl" }).appendTo("#controls") : null ;
                    ($("a#ltr").length == 0) ? $("<a>").attr({ id:"ltr", href:"#", title:"ltr" }).appendTo("#controls") : null ;

                    //variable to hold trigger element
                    var title = $(this).attr("title");

                    //add p if doesn't exist, update it if it does
                    ($("p#title").length == 0) ? $("<p>").attr("id", "title").text(title).appendTo("div#controls") : $("p#title").text(title) ;
                });

                //restart on mouseout
                $("a.wrapper").live("mouseout", function(e) {

                    //hide controls if not hovering on them
                    (e.relatedTarget == null) ? null : (e.relatedTarget.id != "controls") ? $("div#controls").slideUp("slow").remove() : null ;

                    //work out total travel distance
                    var totalDistance = parseInt($("div#container").width()) + parseInt($("div#viewer").width());

                    //work out distance left to travel
                    var distanceLeft = ($("div#container").hasClass("ltr")) ? totalDistance - (parseInt($("div#container").css("left")) + parseInt($("div#container").width())) : totalDistance - (parseInt($("div#viewer").width()) - (parseInt($("div#container").css("left")))) ;

                    //new duration is distance left / speed)
                    var newDuration = distanceLeft / speed;

                    //restart anim
                    animator($("div#container"), newDuration, $("div#container").attr("class"));

                });

                //handler for ltr button
                $("#ltr").live("click", function() {

                    //stop anim
                    $("div#container").stop(true);

                    //swap class names
                    $("div#container").removeClass("rtl").addClass("ltr");

                    //work out total travel distance
                    var totalDistance = parseInt($("div#container").width()) + parseInt($("div#viewer").width());

                    //work out remaining distance
                    var distanceLeft = totalDistance - (parseInt($("div#container").css("left")) + parseInt($("div#container").width()));

                    //new duration is distance left / speed)
                    var newDuration = distanceLeft / speed;

                    //restart anim
                    animator($("div#container"), newDuration, "ltr");
                });

                //handler for rtl button
                $("#rtl").live("click", function() {

                    //stop anim
                    $("div#container").stop(true);

                    //swap class names
                    $("div#container").removeClass("ltr").addClass("rtl");

                    //work out total travel distance
                    var totalDistance = parseInt($("div#container").width()) + parseInt($("div#viewer").width());

                    //work out remaining distance
                    var distanceLeft = totalDistance - (parseInt($("div#viewer").width()) - (parseInt($("div#container").css("left"))));

                    //new duration is distance left / speed)
                    var newDuration = distanceLeft / speed;

                    //restart anim
                    animator($("div#container"), newDuration, "rtl");
                });
            });
        </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line under the "rtl" logic tells the element to keep sliding until -632px (the width of the element).

```
    //animate the el
    el.animate({
        left: "-" + el.width() + "px"
    }, time, "linear", function() {
```

Take off the + "px" and use '-=' instead!

```
    //animate the el
    el.animate({
        left: "-=" + el.width()
    }, time, "linear", function() {
```

I don't really understand why you are taking this approach though. Why not just use this, which would slide it just until it leaves "viewer"?

```
    //animate the el
    el.animate({
        left: ($('div#viewer').offset().left - $('div#container').outerWidth()) + "px"
    }, time, "linear", function() {
```

Also, why is #container so wide? Why not just let it remain the width of the contents? Does it really need to be as wide as .wrapper?

Comment: I tried putting your code in, if you watch all the way to the end, it does the same thing, triple the length. http://www.themonastery.org/jd/slider.php#

Comment: triple the length of what? It's moving the width of #container, which is 630 px wide?

Comment: Watch it now that I took off the hidden, it still will not stop as the last leaves, or better yet, just run itself in a continuous circle. I tried altering the container width with really nasty results.

Comment: Yeah I see now it's not triple the length, it's just moving the total width of the screen before restarting, when I want it to move just the length of viewer plus the length of the slide show.

Comment: If you want it to run in a continuous circle, you need to clone the content, that way one can be running into the screen on the right as the other runs off to the left... when the left one goes out of view, you switch it to the right and they trade roles.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a continuously cycling scroll. I think you may be able to scavenge ideas from it or just use it outright as a starting point; it addresses all the problems you are having, as I understand them. I hope this helps!

http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/FeRUd/11/